# Can I use "or" while writing lex pattern?

Tags: lex

Can I write something like:

```
">" | "<" | "!="  {printf("Operator");}
```

I don't want to repeat same C code for a number of patterns. Is there some way to write multiple patterns like this using lex?

Comment: Just lose the spaces: `">"|"<"|"!=" { printf("Operator"); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one of two ways:

1. Use the `|` regular expression operator (possibly in combination with character classes). Remember that a (f)lex regular expression may not contain unquoted whitespace:

   ```
   ">"|"<"|"!="  {printf("Operator");}
   ```

   or:

   ```
   [<>]|"!="     { printf("Operator");}
   ```

   It is worth reading the [Flex manual section on patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns).
2. Use the special action `|`. In this case, the `|` must be preceded by whitespace and should be the last thing on the line:

   ```
   ">"           |
   "<"           |
   "!="          {printf("Operator");}
   ```

   You'll find examples of the use of this special action in the [Flex manual section on actions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#Actions). Note the requirement (emphasis added):

   > An action consisting **solely** of a vertical bar (‘|’) means “same as the action for the next rule”

Usually, the first alternative will be better, but there are cases (mostly involving the `REJECT` action, as in the somewhat contrived example in the manual) in which the `|` special action can be useful. For complicated patterns, it can make the (f)lex source more readable.